# iOS 7 UITableViewCell Autolayout

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, autolayout

I have two labels in a UITableView and I want them to resize in landscape to each occupy half of the width of the UITableViewCell.  I have tried a few configurations but they always seem to overlap each other.  I'm not sure how to apply constraints to control the width.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add left, top , bottom, right, width (it wil be >=), height, make equal size constraints

Comment: I tried >= but you have to specify a width which is what I am trying to avoid.  I tried replacing the widths with Equal Widths.  It works well in landscape but they overlap in portrait.

Comment: Once I added make equal widths it all came together.  Thanks.